# If $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus\mathfrak{g}_i$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, why does $\mathfrak{h}=\bigoplus\left(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, direct-sum, semisimple-lie-algebras

There is this property about Cartan subalgebras that is not clear to me.

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra. Then I know we can decompose it uniquely as $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus\mathfrak{g}_i$, where the $\mathfrak{g}_i$ are simple ideals. If $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra (maximal toral subalgebra), then $\mathfrak{h}=\bigoplus(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i)$. The $\supseteq$ direction is clear.

Why does the other follow? I thought of something like this, take $x\in\mathfrak{h}$, and write $x=\sum x_i$ for $x_i\in\mathfrak{g}_i$. I want to show $x_i\in\mathfrak{h}$ for each $i$. I did this by induction on the number of nonzero summands. If there is only one summand so $x=x_i$, the claim is clear. If there's more than one summand, I'm not sure how to reduce it to imply the induction, if this is the right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $K$ is the base field.  Fix $h\in\mathfrak{h}$.  Let $h_i\in\mathfrak{g}_i$ be such that $h=\sum\limits_i\,h_i$ (the $h_i$'s are unique).  We claim that $h_i\in\mathfrak{h}$ for all $i$.  Let $t\in\mathfrak{h}$.  Write $t=\sum\limits_{i}\,t_i$ with $t_i\in\mathfrak{g}_i$.  For $i\neq j$, $$\left[t_i,h_j\right]\in\mathfrak{g}_i\cap\mathfrak{g}_j=\{0\}\,,$$ so $\left[t_i,h_j\right]=0$.  Ergo, $$\sum\limits_{i}\,\left[t_i,h_i\right]=[t,h]=0\,.$$  Since $\left[t_i,h_i\right]\in\mathfrak{g}_i$, we conclude that $\left[t_i,h_i\right]=0$ for every $i$.  Thus, $\left[h_i,t\right]=\left[h_i,t_i\right]=0$ for every $t\in\mathfrak{h}$.

Because $h$ is a semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}$, $h_i$ is also a semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}$ (to be proven below).  If $h_i\notin\mathfrak{h}$, then $\mathfrak{h}\oplus K\mathfrak{h}_i$ is a strictly larger toral subalgebra containing $h$, which is a contradiction.  Thus, $h_i\in \mathfrak{h}$ for all $i$, so $h_i\in\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i$.  Therefore, $$h=\sum\limits_i\,h_i\in\bigoplus\limits_i\,\left(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i\right)\,,$$ whence $\mathfrak{h}\subseteq \bigoplus\limits_i\,\left(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i\right)$.  Since it is trivial that $\mathfrak{h}\supseteq \bigoplus\limits_i\,\left(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i\right)$, $\mathfrak{h}= \bigoplus\limits_i\,\left(\mathfrak{h}\cap\mathfrak{g}_i\right)$, as required.

To show that $h_i$ is a semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}$, we let $V^\lambda$ be the eigenspace of $\text{ad}_\mathfrak{g}(h)$ with the eigenvalue $\lambda\in K$.  For each $i$, take $V_i^\lambda$ to be the intersection $V^\lambda\cap\mathfrak{g}_i$.  Trivially, $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\in K}\,V^\lambda_i=\mathfrak{g}_i$.  However, as $V^\lambda_i$ is the eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\text{ad}_{\mathfrak{g}_i}\left(h_i\right)$, we see that $h_i$ is a semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}_i$.  Now, define $\tilde{V}^\lambda_i:=V^\lambda_i$ if $\lambda\neq 0$, and $\tilde{V}^0_i:=V^0_i\oplus\left(\bigoplus\limits_{j\neq i}\,\mathfrak{g}_j\right)$.  Then, $\tilde{V}^\lambda_i$ is the eigenspace of $\text{ad}_\mathfrak{g}\left(h_i\right)$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Since $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda \in K}\,\tilde{V}^\lambda_i=\mathfrak{g}$, we conclude that $h_i$ is a semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in any finite-dimensional Lie algebra over any field.

Recall that a Cartan subalgebra is a nilpotent subalgebra equal to its normalizer. In particular it's maximal nilpotent.

If we have $\mathfrak{g}=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{g}_i$ a direct product of such Lie algebras and $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent and $\mathfrak{h}_i$ is its projection to $\mathfrak{g}_i$, then $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{h}_i$ is nilpotent and contains $\mathfrak{h}$. In particular, if $\mathfrak{h}$ is maximal nilpotent, then we deduce that $\mathfrak{h}=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{h}_i$, that is, $\mathfrak{h}$ is stable under taking projection to the direct summands. This applies in particular when $\mathfrak{h}$ is Cartan.